# What does the dot mean in the printf function

Tags: c++

I'm solving this problem:

> Vanya walks late t night along a straight street of length l, lit by n lanterns. Consider the coordinate system with the beginning of the street corresponding to the point 0, and its end corresponding to the point l. Then the i-th lantern is at the point ai. The lantern lights all points of the street that are at the distance of at most d from it, where d is some positive number, common for all lanterns.
>
> Vanya wonders: what is the minimum light radius d should the lanterns have to light the whole street?

In some test it gives WA expected: ** *'22258199.50000*00', **found:** *'22258200.0000000'*

but in some tests where answer is not integer, my code output correct answer. (i.e. it can output double)

when I saw the solution there was `"printf("%.10f", maxdist/2.)"` instead `"cout << (double)maxdist/2"`

questions:

- why doesn't my code work?
- What means the dot at the end of "`maxdist/2.`"?
- Why there is no `"&`" before variable `maxdist`?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define all(x) (x).begin(), (x).end()
int main(){
    int n, l;
    cin >> n >> l;
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        v.pb(x);
    }
    sort(all(v));
    int maxdist = 2*max(v[0], l-v[n-1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        maxdist = max(maxdist, v[i+1] - v[i]);
    }
    cout << (double)maxdist/2;
}
```

Comment: It's a floating point literal. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal More specifically, in documentation, it's (2) without the optional exponent and suffix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division)

Comment: What `&` before `maxdist` are you talking about? Why and where do you expect the `&` to be??

Comment: Is this one of those "online" judge tests?  If so, some advice on the type of questions -- if the question **requires** you to give floating point results -- **don't take the test and waste your time**.  The reason is that floating point is not exact -- the answer you give may not match perfectly with the answer the "judge" is looking for.  Your particular problem probably doesn't require any floating point calculations anyway.

Comment: Off topic but... please also see ["Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and ["Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

"%.10f" - means floating value of the variable upto 10 decimal places and "." means the decimal point after which any number followed by f will decide how many decimal places the answer would go.